# firebase Cloud function transaction working sporadically

Tags: firebase, triggers, transactions, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the cloud function like so:

```
exports.updateNewsCount = functions.database.ref('/channels/{channelId}/news/{newsId}/') 
.onWrite (event => {
    const channelId = event.params.channelId;
    const newsId = event.params.newsId;
    let CntRef = admin.database().ref('/channelDetails/' + channelId + '/newsCnt');
    if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()){
        return CntRef.transaction(function(current){
            if (current){
                console.log ('current is not null');
                return (current || 0) + 1;
            }
            else {
                console.log('current is null');
                return current;
            }
        },function(error, b, d){
            if (error) 
                console.log(error);
            else 
                console.log ('error is null');
            if (b)
                console.log('boolean is true');
            else
                console.log('boolean is false');

            if (d)
                console.log('snapshot is ' + d);
            else
                console.log ('snapshot is null');
        }).then(()=>{});
    } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()){
        return CntRef.transaction(function(current){
            if (current)
                return (current || 1) - 1;
            else
                return current;
        }, function(error, b, d){if (error) console.log(error); if (d) console.log(d);}).then(()=>{});
    }
});
```

It fires consistently as I can see the log entries.  However, the newsCnt field is not updated as expected.  Sometimes it gets updated and sometimes not!!! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried putting logging in at the various points where you expect the transaction to execute to see what it's actually doing?

Comment: Yes. Have added console.log in multiple places and when it works, the logs are as expected. The cloud function also always returns with status ok. So i know there are no syntax errors.

Comment: The cloud function is fired correctly every time it is required. The function returns with status ok according to the log.  When it works, (my console.logs which I have stripped in the above code) tell me that the transaction was tried twice, once where current was null and a second time when the current was not null.  I have a feeling that maybe there are other cloud functions that are preventing this from finishing or something like that.

Comment: It starts working consistently **after I go to the firebase console and modify the newsCnt field manually (say set it to 1) once.**  It appears that until I do that, firebase does not deem the newsCnt field to be an int field.

Answer (score 2):

You should expect that a transaction be called potentially multiple times, the first time with null.  That's the way transactions work.  Please read the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

In particular note the following callout in that section:

> Note: Because your update function is called multiple times, it must
>   be able to handle null data. Even if there is existing data in your
>   remote database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction
>   function is run, resulting in null for the initial value.

Comment: Yes, I have understood that.  And I think I have taken care of that in my code as well.   I am returning current when current is null.

Comment: If you a provide a function for the onComplete parameter for the transaction and log its parameters, what do you find?  Transactions are definitely not broken.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction

Comment: I have changed the code to include onComplete and console.log's.   My log shows that _current is null_ (twice), _boolean is true_ (once), _snapshot is [object Object]_ (once) and _Function execution took 1297 ms, finished with status: 'ok'_ (once). @Doug

Comment: That's what I would expect if there is no data at the location you're trying to change with a transaction.  If you're trying to update a counter, I think you might be helped with this sample code.  Notice that the checks for existence are *inside* the transaction, while yours are *outside* the transaction): https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count

Comment: And yet that field is very much there.  Having said that, I must highlight that it is not there in every channelDetails node (as I added the field only recently and hence only the newly added channels have that field). On your comment on where the checks for existence should be, my initial code had is on the inside as you have suggested. I changed it because it was not working.  I have written this function in more ways than one can skin a cat, in the last few days!  I have feeling that the cloud function does some optimization in checking if the field exists or not that is not quite right.

Comment: Same behaviour even with the new code (copied from the link you gave).  I deleted my entire database and started from scratch (app is still in development and I have that luxury now) and it is **working for the first few as expected** .  Let me see what happens after I add more data.  Now I am worried what would happen if I have to add a new field as part of version 2 of the app.

Comment: Now another function is not working.   I have another cloud function to update the number of subscribers.  This was working fine.  Now it doesn't.  Log shows that the current is always null and the function returns ok.   It appears that transactions inside cloud functions is broken.  Somebody please help.