# Firebase Transaction acting in an unexpected way - Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is triggered when a user follows another user. The transaction should increment the counter

```
exports.userFollowed = functions.firestore.document("Users/{toUser}/followers/{byUser}").onCreate(userFollowed);
```

Read many forums and docs on how you should also handle the **null** case. Still can't get it to work correctly. I even had the value at the location replaced by 'blabla' which I returned for **null** case.

The Data in the DB would look like the below one at first

```
<uid>
    followers: 0
    following: 0
```

The function that is triggered on follow operation

```
function userFollowed(event) {
   byUserStatsRef = rltd.ref('UserStatistics/' + toUser),
   byUserStatsRef.transaction(byCurrentStats => {
                if (!byCurrentStats) {
                    return 'blabla';
                } else {
                    byCurrentStats.following = parseInt(byCurrentStats.following) + 1
                    return byCurrentStats;
                }

            }, function (error, committed, ss) {
                if (committed) {
                    console.log("committed", committed);
                }
            }, true),
}
```

The count increments incorrectly while testing concurrently. Am i doing anything wrong.

Please note this is trigerred in Cloud Functions (Server SDK)

Answer (score 0):

Transactions may return null in some cases, because the function may be triggered before cachung the new value.

[firebase Cloud function transaction working sporadically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481979/firebase-cloud-function-transaction-working-sporadically)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

'Even if there is existing data in your remote database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction function is run, resulting in null for the initial value.'